# Jekyll remove first in array?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I noticed there is a `remove_first` function in liquid. Is it possible to use this to remove the first in an array?

For example:

```
{% animals = 'animals/cat/dog/bird' | split: '/' | remove_first %}
```

The above doesn't work, as it seems you're supposed to pass in a substring, like I am with split.

Is there anyway to do this with Jekyll liquid tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `shift`:

```
{% assign animals = 'animals/cat/dog/bird' | split: '/' | shift %}
{{animals}}
```

Would give the array:

```
["cat", "dog", "bird"]
```

Comment: I'm using Liquid in Shopify and shoft is not available I think, any alternative?

Comment: @MegaTux use [`offset`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/iteration/#offset) for this

Comment: @Stephen - I don't see `offset` from the API list https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/filters/ .`| slice 1, 999` works fine for an array anyway.